# Filtering of selected option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

How do I filter a table content based on option selected ?
I would need to refresh the table below - each time the option on the select changes.

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="selectedGrade" ng-options="grade.Id as grade.Title for grade in grades"></select>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Description</th> 
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="attr in attributes|filter:{grade:selectedGrade.Title}">
    <td>{{attr.id}}</td>
    <td>{{attr.name}}</td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

**Module**

```
angular.module('Employee',[])
.controller('EmployeeCtl',function($scope){
    $scope.grades=[
       {"id":1,"Title":"MTS"},
       {"id":2,"Title":"SMTS"},
       {"id":3,"Title":"PMTS"},
       {"id":4,"Title":"CMTS"}
    ];
    $scope.attributes=[
       {"id":1,"name":"Greg","grade":"MTS"},
       {"id":2,"name":"Marlon","grade":"SMTS"},
       .........
    ];
});
```

Comment: Your objects don't contain any `grade` property, and you're filtering on the  grade property.

Comment: attributes do contain a grade property

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `{{ selectedGrade }}` to your template. You'll notice that what `selectedGrade` contains is the ID of the selected grade, since you used

```
grade.Id as grade.Title for grade in grades
```

If you want `selectedGrade` to contain a grade object, you should use

```
grade.Title for grade in grades
```

Read the [relevant documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).